# What's the fastest way run setup(exe/msi) files using python?

Tags: python, subprocess, exe, pywinauto, os.system

*Formulation of the problem:*

I want to create console-application which select some setup(exe/msi) files from current script directory and silently (using silent keys) install them. Of course i want to do it as quickly as possible.

*Example:*

For example i want to install 3 different programs: Telegram, 2GIS, 7z. Hence I have 3 installers respectively: tsetup.exe, 2GISShell.msi, 7z-x64.exe. Also i have 3 scripts where i use 3 different ways to install them:

*testos.py:*

```
import os
import time


#os.system

#2gis
print('start time 2gis')
start_time = time.time()
os.system('start ' + '2GISShell.msi /qn')
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

#telegram
print('start time telegram')
start_time = time.time()
os.system('start ' + 'tsetup.exe /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NORESTART /SP-')
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

#7z
print('start time 7z')
start_time = time.time()
os.system('start ' + '7z-x64.exe /S')
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

*output:*

```
start time 2gis
--- 0.06574773788452148 seconds ---
start time telegram
--- 0.020944833755493164 seconds ---
start time 7z
--- 0.02792501449584961 seconds ---
```

*testsub.py:*

```
import time
import subprocess

#subprocess

#telegram
print('start time telegram')
start_time = time.time()
subprocess.call('tsetup.exe /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NORESTART /SP-')
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

#7z
print('start time 7z')
start_time = time.time()
subprocess.call('7z-x64.exe /S')
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

*output:*

```
start time telegram
--- 2.4023494720458984 seconds ---
start time 7z
--- 0.18584489822387695 seconds ---
```

*testpywin.py:*

```
import time
from pywinauto.application import Application

#pywinauto

#telegram
print('start time telegram')
start_time = time.time()
Application(backend='uia').start('tsetup.exe /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NORESTART /SP-')
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

#7z
print('start time 7z')
start_time = time.time()
Application(backend='uia').start('7z-x64.exe /S')
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

*output:*

```
start time telegram
--- 0.14841079711914062 seconds ---
start time 7z
--- 0.1946101188659668 seconds ---
```

*Question:*

Are there any better (faster) ways to run setup files?

Thank you for your attention.
I will be glad to receive any additional information on this issue.

Comment: How many times did you repeat each timing? A setup executable is not particularly special over any other program so what method you use to run it might not make a lot of difference compared to the time it takes the installer to run. Keep in mind also the same program can run faster on repeat runs, e.g. if the binary image is already paged in memory, or in the case of installers it might have already extracted some temporary files, etc.

Comment: How long installation takes isn't going to be affected by any of this. (The case that looked like it went faster probably didn't wait for the installation to finish.)

Comment: @Iguananaut I took into account the fact that after installing the program once, on subsequent launches, the program can be installed faster. Therefore, before each test, I installed and uninstalled programs so that everything was on an equal footing.

Comment: I edited the post a bit and now I use os.system() more correctly. And from now os.system() work more faster then other methods. The question remains open whether there are more efficient methods or how to use these methods more correctly. I will be especially grateful if someone explains how each of the methods works internally.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Perhaps I somehow incorrectly expressed myself, sorry, but it is clearly visible that launching (perhaps not installing) the installation files using os.system() is clearly faster